# jQuery handeling of several inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is a little complicated..
My system has this module for staffs, so if they have spend their own money on company-related stuff, the can ask for getting then payed back. On a list, there can be as many lines as the user wants to add, and this is where my problem begins.

I want my code to take all the data from the inputs, and write them into a textarea (where PHP will explode it all)

My code is here: (check **http://jsfiddle.net/ZWq9z/**)

```
<form id="test">
    <div><input type="date" /><input type="text" placeholder="Purpose" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" /><input type="text" placeholder="Price" /><input type="text" placeholder="Attachments" /></div>
    <div><input type="date" /><input type="text" placeholder="Purpose" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" /><input type="text" placeholder="Price" /><input type="text" placeholder="Attachments" /></div>
    <div><input type="date" /><input type="text" placeholder="Purpose" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" /><input type="text" placeholder="Price" /><input type="text" placeholder="Attachments" /></div>
</form>
<a id="new">add line</a>
<textarea id="all"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(){
    $("#all").val("");
    $("#test div").each(function(i){
        $("input").each(function(i){
            if($(this).val() != ""){
                $("#all").val($("#all").val() + ";" + $(this).val());
            }
        });
        $("#all").val($("#all").val() + ";\n");
    });
});
$("#new").click(function(){
    $("#test").append('<div><input type="date" /><input type="text" placeholder="Purpose" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" /><input type="text" placeholder="Price" /><input type="text" placeholder="Attachments" /></div>');
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZWq9z/**

If you can help me solve this (or come up with a better solution), i will be very grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: Where are the form field names? Why would you not just post the form to the server instead of trying to combine everything into a text area?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my jfiddle acct on hand but here it is with a minor variation to your code.
Update: found jsfiddle login (damn username instead of email, doh): http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/ZWq9z/6/

```
$(document).keyup(function(){
    $("#all").val("");
    $("#test").children("div").each(function(i){
        $(this).children("input").each(function(i){
            if($(this).val() != ""){
                $("#all").val($("#all").val() + ";" + $(this).val());
            }
        });
        $("#all").val($("#all").val() + ";\n");
    });
});
$("#new").click(function(){
   $("#test").append('<div><input type="date" /><input type="text" placeholder="Purpose" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description" /><input type="text" placeholder="Price" /><input type="text" placeholder="Attachments" /></div>');
});
```